# I updated to Xcode 8 beta 6 and I am getting very weird errors

Tags: ios, xcode8-beta6

I just update to Xcode 8 beta 6 and got an overload of errors (no surprise), I got most of them sorted out, but there are two errors which I am unsure of how to fix.

For this I get this error `Method does not override any method from its superclass`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "***"){

    }
}
```

And for this I get this error `init has been renamed to init(describing:)`

```
return String(self.type)
```

Comment: See [SE-0116](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md) & [SE-0089](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0089-rename-string-reflection-init.md)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method signature has changed in Xcode 8 now it is the following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   // Code here
}
```

Comment: I believe ```fun``` above should be ```func```. Just in case someone is cutting and pasting this code. Thanks for the answer; I'll remember to check the method signature in the future for changes.

Answer (score 9):

You should use

`String(describing: self.type)`

instead of

`String(self.type)`

Answer (score 3):

Basically AnyObject is now Any in most functions